# Prevent execution of sender channel until spawned executor channels from splitter finish processing in Spring Integration

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-integration

Currently, my program is executing in a single-threaded way, where it goes through the context file and makes various HTTP requests, and those responses from the HTTP requests are used to create a final response using XSLT. I am now trying to multi-thread some of these requests because only the data from the first HTTP request is necessary to use in the subsequent requests.

So far I have created a splitter who spawns 5 different messages. The output channel is an ExecutorChannel with a thread pool size of 5. The output channel is a header value router that uses a header that was added in the splitter in order to decide which part of the context file to send the message to.

```
<splitter input-channel="spliter-input" output-channel="splitter-output" ref="MultiThreadedSplitter" method="split" />

<channel id="splitterRouter">
   <dispatcher task-executor="splitterExecutor" />
<channel/>
<task:executor id="splitterExecutor" pool-size="5" /> 

<header-value-router input-channel="splitter-output" header-name="splitHeader">
  <mapping value="httpRequest1" channel="httpRequest1" />
  ...
  <mapping value="httpRequest5" channel="httpRequest5" />
<header-value-router/>
```

The above are all working as I can see in the logs that I generate that the requests are being made in a multi-threaded fashion all with different thread contexts. Except the issue that I am having is that it seems that the original thread is trying to continue down the context file and finishes the sending and receiving of the message so the class that I created that extends MessagingGatewaySupport tries to receive the response message but the response message is null and thus results in a null pointer exception. The 5 threads that were spawned continue to execute and I can see that the requests are being made successfully and in the end, I can see the final response that I want to be returned but the original thread already sent the null pointer error back.

Is there a way to prevent the execution of the main thread that originally called the splitter?

@Artem thanks in advance for helping with this :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It look like your `MessagingGatewaySupport` is configured with too short `replyTimeout`. Since you send splitted messages into different threads there is no blocking in the caller any more, so it just goes to the `receive()` part for the reply.

See

```
/**
 * Set the timeout value for receiving reply messages. If not
 * explicitly configured, the default is one second.
 * @param replyTimeout the timeout value in milliseconds
 */
public void setReplyTimeout(long replyTimeout) {
```

and `private static final long DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = 1000L;`

This all going to be good if you really return some reply in the end.
If you don't have it at all and still would like to block until some event, consider to use a `Barrier` component: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/message-routing.html#barrier

Comment: Is there a way to set the replyTimeout on a per channel basis? For instance I only want the aggregator input channel to have an increased replyTimeout?

Comment: Yes, you can specify a `receiveTimeout` header in the message you send.

Comment: In my splitter, I have this line: `Message<String> newMessage = MessageBuilder.withPayload(message.getPayload)).copyHeaders(message.getHeaders()).setHeader("customHeader", "example").setHeader("receiveTimeout", 60000).build()` In an attempt to add the receiveTimeout header on the message that the splitter generates, I see it on the message that is created but it still seems like the channel is not waiting for the subsequent messages once one is received.

Comment: >  channel is not waiting 

I'm not sure what are you talking about. Please, be more specific and maybe even share some config on the matter in your question. Please, also consider to not add a long code into a comments. It is just not readable. It is fine with me to have more edits in your question and in my answer. Although it might even be better to have a new SO thread since it looks like we are shifting a context a little bit already.